# How to install local package tarball file using ng add command?

Tags: angular-cli

I have tried to use `ng add` for my local package (eg `ng add "file:ng-control.tgz"`).

It throws an error `could not find module "file:ng-control.tgz"`.

If I add my package manually in the project package json as `"ng-control":"file:ng-control.tgz"` and then run `ng add ng-control` it works fine with package installed and schematics run successfully, but I am hoping to find a cleaner more explicit way to do this.

Something like (eg `ng add "file:ng-control.tgz"`) 
The `ng add` command should work.

How can i do that?

Comment: what do you expect the command `ng add "file:ng-control.tgz"` to do?

Comment: I expect ng add should work for local tarball file also because npm support install of local package tarball file...

Comment: I'm not an expert on CLI, it's possible they you may need to define something like that https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/schematics/collection.json for your project. The `schematics` functionality is involved in all this. You may need to figure how it all works. Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient knowledge in this area

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```sh
ng add path/to/local/file.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1. Copy the *library.tgz* file to root folder of your angular App
2. Use the following command `ng add library.tgz`

It will add and install the package to your angular app